# Is it possible to swap positions of two children of div and animate it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I am doing bubble sort with the elements of an array whose data is taken from a textarea. I take the data from textarea, put it into an array and I append each of the element of the array to a div called `chars` in `appendThem()` function. So, is there any way I can animate the swap between the elements that happens during the sorting process? I used `var array = new Array()` because `bubbleSort()` function is defined in another file and I wanted to access `array` globally. I am only swapping the innerHTML here. I could not figure out a way to swap the children. Is it possible to swap the children and also animate the same?

```
var board = document.getElementsByClassName("chars")[0];
var array= new Array();

function appendthem(){
    var input = document.getElementById("charInput").value; 
    input = input.replace(/ /g,'')
    array = input.split(",");


    while (board.firstChild) {
        board.removeChild(board.lastChild);
    }  //Removing any existing children from old data when new data is entered

    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        var elem = document.createElement("p");
        elem.style.marginLeft="20px";
        var textnode  = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
        elem.appendChild(textnode);
        board.appendChild(elem);    
    }
        bubbleSort();
}

function bubbleSort(){
    for(var m=0; m<array.length; m++){
        isSwapped =false;

        for(var j=0; j<array.length-m-1; j++){
            if(  Number(board.children[j].innerHTML) > Number(board.children[j+1].innerHTML) ){
                    var temp = board.children[j].innerHTML;
                    board.children[j].innerHTML = board.children[j+1].innerHTML;    
                    board.children[j+1].innerHTML = temp;
                isSwapped = true;
            }
        }

      if( !isSwapped ){
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

CSS of `chars` div, if required:

```
.chars{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
}
```

UPDATE:
Added HTML on request:

```
<html>
    <head>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="algorithms/bubble.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<div class="container">
        
        <div class="textbox">
            <textarea id="charInput" placeholder="Enter numbers or letters separated by commas."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="board">
            <div class="chars"></div>
        </div>

<button class="submitBtn" onclick="appendthem()" >Sort!</button>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi can you add your HTML as wel?

Comment: I have added the HTML.